# Print array from database in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have node.js and other stuff working fine just when I pass the data from database to jade and print them instead of names i want, the output is  [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]

here is my code
at index.js

```
router.get('/schoolinfo', function(req, res){
  connection.query('select Name from here', function(err,rows,fields){
    if(!err){
      res.render('name.jade', { title: 'title', database: [rows]});
    }
    else{
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

and at name.jade

```
p test #{database.toString()}
each val in #{database} <-- error here
     a(href='/person/' + val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `a(href='/person'+val.name) #{val.name}`

Comment: i tried it but it still doesn't work. the url part becomes http://localhost:3000/name/undefined and the names is not shown on the page.

Comment: the link works fine, it directs me to the correct page with some data, which i can't tell if it is correct since i can only see localhost:3000/name/undefined.    and also im trying to output the data as a string, but val.name doesn't shows anything. in addition, i made a change in the js file, which is that "res.render('name.jade', { title: 'title', database: rows});"